# How to use facet on group response in solr query?

Tags: solr, faceted-search

i want to use facet on a particular field which is returned by a group query.I mean, say 100 docs are returned by the group query on field video_format and in those 100 docs a particular field say video_id value is same in different  docs,so i want to facet with field name video_id  so that i will get the count of those video ids for a particular video_format.
Please help me if u have solution.

Answer (score 0):

[group.facet](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters) should allow you to facet on the group results.

Comment: I tried this,but it was not returning facet inside group response